# How to log current public SSH key?

Tags: ssh

How do you find the public SSH key that's currently being used by your session to login? I'm trying to log SSH access for multiple SSH keys, and I can't find any way to tell what key was last used to login.

Comment: You want to run ssh in verbose mode: ssh -v <rest of command line>

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461612/117549